# Dynamically calling a method in a class

Tags: php

I've recently worked on some code in which I had to dynamically call a method inside a class.

The solution I ended up using was 2 lines, because the "dynamic" part was only a small section of the actual method name that I needed to call.

This is the solution I ended up using:

```
$pull = "pull_{$type}_day"; 
$day = $download->$pull();
```

Originally, I tried to make this a single line, but it did not work. In a technical sense, why does the above code work but the below code does not?

```
$day = $download->"pull_{$type}_day"();
```

Comment: try this -  `$day = $download->{"pull_{$type}_day"}();`  [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eec9ab225abfbdbbf637c24dbb8a76465937e35a)  I know it looks a bit "funny" but PHP understands things like this `${"foo"}` etc.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix That does work

Comment: The inner brackets are needed to make sure that `$type` is not `$type_day` as PHP will think that is a variable because the `_` is legal.  if it's a string you can just do `{"some_method"}()` etc.  I suppose you could do concatenation in there too `.`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Yeah that makes sense, and would be a good answer to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a string or part of a string as a method (or property) you need to surround it in `{}` like this:

```
#property
echo $foo->{"bar"};

#method call
echo $foo->{"bar"}();
```

So if you need a variable in the string part, this follows the same rules as any normal string.

```
 echo $foo->{"bar".$bar}();
 echo $foo->{'bar'.$bar.'bar'}();
 echo $foo->{"bar{$bar}bar"}();
```

And so on.  Here is a full example

```
class foo{

    function pull_1_day(){
        echo "bar";
    }
}

$a = 1;

(new foo)->{"pull_{$a}_day"}();
```

Outputs

```
  bar
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eec9ab225abfbdbbf637c24dbb8a76465937e35a)

This follows in the same way PHP allows you to use a string as a variable such as this:

```
$foo = 'bar';
echo ${"foo"};
```

Outputs

```
bar
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4f8a7ac8e65d8d94b40d3bb82b27921b5ca226a4)

Same kind of syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)?

I find it easier to read and parse.

Assuming you have:

```php
class pull {
    public function pull_foo_day () {
        echo "hello";
    }
}

$pull = new pull();
$type = "foo";
```

You can simply do:

```php
call_user_func([$pull, "pull_{$type}_day"]);
```

Outputs:

> hello

See it working [here](https://3v4l.org/gToVg).

Comment: OP is asking how to do it in one line.

Comment: @EternalHour call_user_func allows you to do it one line. All the rest as well. all the rest had to be setup beforehand no matter what they did (the value for `$type` and `$pull` had to be known beforhand)